# PHP mysqli query isnt working

Tags: php, database, authentication, mysqli

when the user enters their details they click on login but its not working, my connection to the database is fine its this file that is not working, any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
include '../connection.php'; //used to include connection file that is 1 level higher in the directory 

$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$fquery = 'SELECT Username FROM login LIMIT 0, 30 ';
$squery = 'SELECT Password FROM login LIMIT 0, 30 ';

$username_query = mysqli_query($dbc, $fquery);
$password_query = mysqli_query($dbc, $squery);

$username_row = mysqli_fetch_array($username_query);
$password_row = mysqli_fetch_array($password_query);

if($username == $username_row && $password == $password_row) {
    echo 'username and password correct';
}


?>
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? A blank screen? An error message? The wrong data returned?

Comment: Also, you might want to look at the logic in your queries; you're looking to see if the username and password are present in the table, but not necessarily for the same account....

Comment: Just as a note, this is never going to work. You are assuming you will never have more than 30 users/passwords, and then comparing a request variable to an array, and not making sure that the user actually matches up to the password.

Comment: @andrewsi the form shows nothing when i click enter, it just stays the same

Comment: There seems to be some pieces missing in your logic.  Have you actually stepped through and debugged your code to see what each variable is?  Or at least what you're queries are and what they return?

Comment: but at least there is no sql-injetion!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

include '../connection.php'; //used to include connection file that is 1 level higher in the directory 

$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$query = 'SELECT Username FROM login WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?';

/* set a default value to check against */
$valid_user = '';

/* use prepared statement */
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($dbc);
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
    /* set question marks equal to values */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* get the valid username only if query is successful */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $valid_user);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    /* close the statment */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}


/* check if default was overwritten */
if($valid_user != '') {
    echo 'username and password correct';
}
?>
```

Try this out, should accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $username_query = mysqli_query($dbc, $fquery);
     $password_query = mysqli_query($dbc, $squery);       
     $username_row   = $username_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     $password_row   = $password_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);        

     if($username == $username_row['username'] && $password == $password_row['Password']) {
       echo 'username and password correct';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_REQUEST['password']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password' LIMIT 1";

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
    echo 'username and password correct';
```